# Construct a free chain complex K

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-groups

Let $(A_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be a set of finitely presented abelian groups. Construct a chain complex $\mathbf{K}$, with each $K_{n}$ a free abelian group, such that for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $H_{n}(\mathbf{K}) \cong A_{n}$.

I have no idea where to start with this. How can I go from a graded abelian group to a free complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to construct a chain complex $K$ such that $H_n(K)=A$ for a given $n$ and $A$, and $H_j(K)=0$ for $j\neq n$ (then you pass to a direct sum of such $K$'s). This can be done by defining a left free resolution $\ldots E^2\stackrel{\partial_2}{\to}  E^1\stackrel{\partial_1}{\to} E_0 \stackrel{\epsilon}{\to}  A\to 0$, letting $E$ to be the chain complex consisting of $E_j$'s and the differentials (ending with $\to E_0\to 0$), which has a unique homology $H_0\simeq A$ and finally you define $K_*=E_{*+n}$.